# Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements WHEN INSERT LIST

Tags: apex

```
List<OperacionComercial__c> OCCambioPlanETBTotal = new List<OperacionComercial__c>();
    
List<LTE_DetalleOferta__c> lstDO = new List<LTE_DetalleOferta__c>();
for(OperacionComercial__c objOC : OCCambioPlanETBTotal){
    for(LTE_DetalleOferta__c objDO : detalleOfertaCambioPlan){
        if(objOC.Plan__c == objDO.Plan__c ){
            objDO.LTE_OperacionComercial__c = objOC.Id;
            objDO.LTE_Oferta_Economica__c = reservaCambioPlan[countReserva].Id;
            lstDO.add(objDO);
        }
    }
                    
    insert lstDO;
```

When inserting me it is giving the error

> System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements

Comment: Your code has several other issues (`if(a == b)` inside of a nested loop is bad, dml in a loop is bad, your outermost `for()` is never closed). That makes it difficult to determine where the actual problem is.

Comment: Hoi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. It would be helpful if you explained the business logic behind the code, so we can understand how best to help you. You can [edit] your question to include more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because you have the same object in memory in two or more indices.

Here's a simple reproduction of your error:

```
Account demo = new Account[0];
Account[] accounts = new Account[] { demo, demo };
insert accounts; // Error here
```

Your nested for loop is causing the problem. There are two or more `OperacionComercial__c` in the list have the same `Plan__c`, so with the inner loop, the `objDO` record is added two or more times.

I can't tell you what the best solution is, because I don't know the intended business logic, but I can tell you you're going to have to rethink your design, because even if you fix this, you're not going to get the results you expect, I believe.